# Disconnected USB drive continues to trigger drive failure alert Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, usb-drive, disk-management

I have been putting up with this for months and decided to ask if anyone knows how to get rid of this. I had a Sandisk Extreme Portable USB drive I used for games and would switch use between computers (yes I safely eject). Even though Kubuntu said it was failing (Win never did) it took awhile before I disconnected it and put in for the warranty replacement. I now got the new drive (have not installed yet) but cannot get rid of this notice every reboot. There must be someplace that a prior mounting of that old drive "lives" and I need it gone before installing the new one. I have one internal SSD, one USB flash drive (currently empty) & one WD Easystore external HDD attached to my desktop.This drive does not even show up in Dolphin. Screenshot included.[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I continued looking online for a solution and finally found this: Activities-Disk-Device Viewer-SMART Status. Here the disk in question, which was previously mounted on sdb1 (a different empty flash drive is currently mounted on sdb1), shows the error message I get upon reboot and has an option to IGNORE. [image]

Selecting ignore (it's a toggle) displays "monitor". But after a reboot, no longer getting disk fail message. Success.